# Does google delete users passwords that are saved in that account permanently after user has deleted their google account?

Tags: google-chrome, password-protection, google-account

Please read everything before answering

what happend to all password in a google account if I delete my Google account? Will it deletes all the password too?

Story here

(Im honestly not scared about "it will be deleted", i actually really wanted it to be deleted)

Im just forgot to check if there is a password saved on that account (i have exported it to other account but i forgot to delete it (on that account))

i already deleted the account and i cant recover that account anymore (why i tried recover that google account?. just to check if there is still password saved in there)

Google "delete account policy" doesnt explain what data exactly will be deleted (they only say few google services).The closest one that related to google password manager is chrome but they doesnt talk about the deletion of the password saved in that google account at all

Im just really concerned right now

Will those password be deleted too?

Note: the account has been deleted long time ago

Comment: I think this question would be better for the [Google support forum](https://support.google.com/).